# How to convert a matrix of stl vectors to matrix of 2d arrays (or to 1d array)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, cuda

I'm using CUDA but it seems i can't  pass STL vectors as parameters so i need to convert those matrix of vectors to a dynamic array.

`std::vector< std::vector<float> > some_matrix;`  to   `float **f;`

i tried to use the memcpy function but for some reason it does't work as expect, if i try to copy the contents, some of the values in the original matrix are changed for garbage. 
i'm avoiding using for cycles because that would reduce the efficiency.

Comment: How did you do before? You could show your code and let others help fix the bugs if any.

Comment: std::vector is for host use only. I would recommend using thrust library.

Comment: ok, i'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @JackOLantern: But thrust only supports POD types, so the naïve thrust device vector of thrust device vectors approach won't work here.

Comment: @talonmies Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding the poster's question, but I would say that his problem is that he cannot pass `std::vector` as parameter to CUDA APIs or kernels. Instead of using `std::vector`, would using the thrust library as `thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr = thrust::device_malloc<int>(N);` and the using a raw pointer as `int* raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dev_ptr);` work?

Comment: I'll be very impressed if you can copy `std::vector< std::vector<float> > some_matrix` to any usable flattened data structure without a loop of some sort.

Comment: @JackOLantern: The key part of this question is that the source memory is a vector of vectors. The only point I was making is that thrust vector doesn't support non POD types, so it would be impossible to do the most obvious thing and just replace `std::vector< std::vector<float> >` with `thrust::device_vector< thrust::device_vector<float> >`. I read your comment as implying the latter.

Comment: @talonmies Ok. I interpreted the poster's question as a beginner question, i.e., of someone who is new to CUDA and is trying to write CUDA codes with the inertia of being used to C++ `std::vector`. Therefore I was suggesting using thrust to begin writing a new code from scratch. I have read your answer and indeed it approaches the question from a different perspective. If one has already a code using `std::vector`, how to solve the problem of coping it to the GPU and then passing the array/matrix as a parameter to a CUDA kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, it isn't possible to pass a `std::vector` to a CUDA kernel and use it within the kernel code, and it isn't possible to pass a simple array of host pointers you might construct from a `std::vector< std::vector<float> >` to a CUDA kernel either.

What you need to do is firstly create a host array of *device pointers* (so one entry for each row you copy to the device) and the copy that array of pointers to the device. This means you need a cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy call per matrix row or column you copy to the device. You could do it like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<float> > some_matrix;

float** f = new float*[some_matrix.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < some_matrix.size(); ++i) {
    size_t szp = sizeof(float) * some_matrix[i].size();
    float* p;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&p, sz);
    cudaMemcpy(p, &some_matrix[i][0], szp, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    f[i] = p;
}

float** f_dev;
size_t szf =  sizeof(float*) * some_matrix.size();
cudaMalloc((void **)&f_dev, szf);
cudaMemcpy(f_dev, f, szf, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or tested, use at own risk]

After this `f_dev` can be passed safely to a CUDA kernel and used on the device.

Hopefully you can see from the above code why this sort of data structure isn't very easy to use on the GPU. There is a lot of API overhead to set it up and transfer it, and then on the device you have a latency penalty because of the double pointer indirection required to fetch a value to memory.

A flattened column major or row major array stored in linear memory is a much better solution for cases where the source data isn't a "jagged array" (ie. all the rows in the matrix are the same length). If the source array is jagged, consider using a structure similar to the CSR or CSC sparse matrix formats. These don't offer much performance improvement on the device, but they do cut down on the host side API overhead to manage them.